# Counting the number columns that contain a value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table, with a changing number of columns, filled with strings which looks like the following:

```
#   A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1  abc xyz abc abc abc xyz xyz
2  xyz xyz abc xyz abc xyz xyz
3  abc abc xyz abc abc xyz xyz
4  abc xyz abc xyz abc xyz xyz
```

I want to know how many of these columns contain the value `abc`. I am not interested in the number of `abc` cells, just the number of `abc` columns.

I'm looking to have an output in another sheet which looks like the following:

```
item to check | # Cols Containing Value
     abc                   5
     xyz                   6
```

I know I can do this in GAS by using a simple for loop which is variable based on max rows and columns, but I am looking for a solution by using native Google Sheets functions.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Convert presence/absence of "abc"s to 1/0
- Transpose the resulting matrix and use matrix multiplication to sum  accross columns
- Count the number of cells of the resulting array, which are above 0

#### Sample Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(IF(A1:G4="abc",1,0)),ROW(A1:A4)^0),">0"))
```

Comment: This is a really creative solution that totally works if you know the number of columns and rows, but how would you do this if the number of columns and rows varies?

Comment: I figured out how to manipulate this, thank you for the suggestion! I will post the full answer shortly.